# Property 'id' is missing in type 'Record<string, string | undefined>' but required in type '{ id: string; }'

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get this `router` function to infer the route params from a path provided, and to check that a `plugin` has the correct function shape.

Here's what I have so far:

```
interface RouteConfig<Path extends string = string> {
  hash?: string;
  name: string;
  path: Path;
  plugins?: Array<RouterPlugin<Path>>;
  search?: string;
}

type Route<Path extends string> = RouteConfig<Path> & {
  plugins: Array<RouterPlugin<Path>>;
};

interface RouteContext<Params = { [key: string]: string | undefined }, Query = Record<string, string>> {
  name: string;
  params: Params;
  query: Query;
  url: URL;
}

type RouterPlugin<Path extends string> = (context: RouteContext<PathParams<Path>>) => void | Promise<void>;

type PathParams<Path extends string> = string extends Path
  ? Record<string, string | undefined>
  : // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    Path extends `${infer _Start}:${infer Param}/${infer Rest}`
    ? { [K in Param | keyof PathParams<Rest>]: string }
    : // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
      Path extends `${infer _Start}:${infer Param}`
      ? { [K in Param]: string }
      : Record<string, unknown>;


function createRouter<T extends RouteConfig>(config: T[]) {
  //
}

const router = createRouter([
  {
    name: 'task',
    path: '/tasks/:id',
    plugins: [(ctx: { params: { id: string }}) => {}], // ERROR HERE
  },
]);
```

And this is the error:

```
Property 'id' is missing in type 'Record<string, string | undefined>' but required in type '{ id: string; }'
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=43&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsCukDC6QzADmAPAApxgAWyEAHpCACYDOyLYUoRyAvO524A%20ZAG8AUMmRU4LKgH4AXAK4giAbknIQcALYRlHVRq0AHSlWUVqmqaYA2mIqBZLkAQShQ4ATxIZsaDJHZxByCyEhW3YIOCgEBUNBNU0AX3FxMB9TFADIcOpaBghmNiNhPjQsXHxCUmsqEQAyMTMQl2VPbz88oPawhsi0zXFQSFhEXOqIPHB6MHDvXTZ%20UWQAbQBrCB8k4wBdPe5kAB9kTGYIQhAIJmRUgBpkAEVMaB9K1AgEdCgmEnKaiegKIkVaUh0%20iOKTMcT0LCscOW0QAjm8oLsXuifNFMFB7MoAKqoAAyaQyWRyVUCUGCTlABRo8xKrBUFX4AAofnMGMperNIAxGRQlixGZEAJR8EQAN3QwDuZzIUHQumALAgJDlCqiFOyKAaIvhjKKjFZIJE-BBppZbAaWnkaG%20v3%20IOByR4ZwuTCuoFuQi0ygA9EHaCx7GMALRMdVwABG9ggkZuDEjEZuyAAApSICwEFxTGBI7n02AgyB0JGLpgNUxIzK4iwtFIGjbSsgAAYAElEoBg0GQAH0AMpgOJgVKKHt9gdG3SpIPTggDr4cVId5vIR1rdYAaWQoGQc9OyG2PnQMCPFjnYtXYCEhzZanum%20DoZLUZjLHjieT8zTfpZjmeYFkWH7gOWlbVrW9aNpuLYWG2rLdr2y5QEOo7jpOS79uhc7rvBW5iBs%206HnOj7WukUjUcgfLOn8AIek8FybBWADuIC6hkMAXAgYDAPgyD5rEkC9FAJAACpIWw-K1MQQhcnJRDKBJ6z7FKEhSCG4jpOI3IcMgKo0pUwmUBAYkcusWiadRkIGMgADkY4sJsDkPJu5jUMoDlBs5mwsEGigKm5Hn9AiGxcmAdDKGs5iijFB5MNCPCpKkUq8CIoipPs7lSI84jqeoQA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to have the generic parameter be a RouteConfig, you should make it the array (tuple) of paths. Then you can map over that tuple and easily define each element of that tuple with `Route<...>`:

```
function createRouter<Paths extends string[]>(config: [...{
    [K in keyof Paths]: Route<Paths[K]>;
}]) {
    //
}
```

And this works nicely:

```
// inferred as createRouter<["/tasks/:id", "/user/:name"]>
const router = createRouter([
    {
        name: "task",
        path: "/tasks/:id",
        plugins: [(ctx) => { ctx.params.id }], // okay
    },
    {
        name: "by user",
        path: "/user/:name",
        plugins: [(ctx) => { ctx.params.name }], // okay
    },
]);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsCukDC6QzADmAPAApxgAWyEAHpCACYDOyLYUoRyAvO524A+ZAG8AUMinIqcFlQD8ALgFcQRANyTpIOAFsIKjms3apAB0pUVFalunJzAG0xFQLZcgCCUKHACeJBjY0GQubiDkVkJC9tIsEHBQCIpGgupaAL7i4mD+5ijBkFHUtAwQzGzGwnxoWLj4hKS2VCIAZGJmjuHuKj5+gUWhPZEtMVla4qCQsIiF9RB44PRgJF0Ufnps-KLIANoA1hD+aSYAuqfcyAA+yJjMEIQgEEzImQA0XQCKmND+tagIAh0FAmCRqup3qphJ8RBIHLoDJcMl1LJsWDYkvoWHEpABHX5QE7IH5-XF3KBOFQAVVQABksjk8gU6iEoGFXKASjQVhVWND1CJ+AAKLrA5YMFRDJaQBjcjbY7kxT4ASj4IgAbuhgK9bmQoOg9MAEiQtTrYkz8igWgqttyyox+RCiEKBTxeZVkC0ugo0ECQWDnVDnTc7g8ni8hF0VAB6GO0FhOaYAWiYxrgACMnBBk88GMmk89kAABZkQFgILjmMDJ8uFsAxkDoZP3TAJJjJjVJFjrKwOvlsAAGABJRKAYNBkAB9ADKYCSYEySlH48ntsyMZXBEngI4mUHPrE+wA0shQF6sXpQ0d-OgYBfqLaWEFy2AhBc3W9o8g4wn66n0yzHM8xrQsUFLK0KyrGs62mRtm1bdtO27XtSg9fkRzHbcoGnOcFyXLcJxw9cDwcX1dj2U9z1tD8Q2yBwpX9UFwXSIgoXuA4mwAdxAC1xBge4EDAYB8GQStEkgIYoG5Nh0KqVi9jOIRhXFJoVD2AA6LT4WkSizxAZAbzvB8qBYD8hhkyilKyM41R0qQ43EbJxHFDhkANNlanEygICk4U9i6eyHGQRFDGQAAiecWAOcLPmC6RLGoFRwpjKKDhYGMlB1WKugcZxORADF9hUsA6DVXg4TE0qNLRbENJ1N4zji6QPkC3KdH0MLwozf422gHL4osKxkpjPqoEy0KBsG-KIiKvYSrK9UjyEugasvFgNNCxrmqkVrbK0IA)